# Android how to customize date in listview

Tags: android

I want to show the date from current date on words in list view .How to customize that date.Could please any one tell me.For example when u booking ticket in railways it's showing the current date on-wards.Like that i want to implement.

```
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NPXA.png
```

Comment: What you have done for that?

Comment: Hi Karan,i haven't done nothing for that .Karan could u understand what i wrote.

Comment: If i understand properly then You want to show data in listview after current date

Comment: I want to show from current date on words.like booking tickets showing current date.

Comment: Please explain in details what exactly you are trying to implement.

Comment: hi dhuma ,open this link.i want to show like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/3NPXA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the SimpleDateFormat for example

```
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("c - LLLL");
    String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(d);//Mon - June for that format
```

Check the formats (yyyy,dd ...) in [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Code for **checking** date **after** or **before** **today**.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// set the calendar to start of today
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

// and get that as a Date
Date today = c.getTime();

// or as a timestamp in milliseconds
long todayInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

// user-specified date which you are testing
// let's say the components come from a form or something
int year = 2011;
int month = 5;
int dayOfMonth = 20;

// reuse the calendar to set user specified date
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

// and get that as a Date
Date dateSpecified = c.getTime();

// test your condition
if (dateSpecified.before(today)) {
  System.err.println("Date specified [" + dateSpecified + "] is before today [" + today + "]");
} else {
  System.err.println("Date specified [" + dateSpecified + "] is NOT before today [" + today + "]");
}
```

**Done**